# check FB authorization (JS SDK) on server side

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk

On client side i call FB.login and get response:

- accessToken
- expiresIn
- signedRequest
- userID

how i can check that is data is correct data, not fabricated ?

Comment: Debug the access token, or decode the signed request.

Comment: @CBroe can you tell how decode the signed request ? Debug the access token means call FB api by this token ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login#parsingsr